# How to add dynamic input field that does not disappear on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to add input fields, as well as remove, on clicking a button.

I can add input boxes using jQuery, but I don't know the way to make it permanent. Do I need to save it in the database to make it permanent? I am using the following code with a button:

```
<div class="input_fields_container">
  <div><input type="text" name="product_name[]">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary add_more_button">Add More Fields</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery is as follows:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var max_fields_limit = 10; // Set limit for maximum input fields
    var x = 1; // Initialize counter for text box
    $('.add_more_button').click(function (e) { // Click event to add more fields
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields_limit) { // Check conditions
            x++; // Increment counter
            $('.input_fields_container').append('<div><input type="text" name="product_name[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field" style="margin-left:10px;">Remove</a></div>'); // Add input field
        }
    });  
    $('.input_fields_container').on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { // User click on remove text links
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    })
});
</script>
```

How do I make it dynamic, so `input` field does not disappear on page refresh until I remove it?

Comment: save the values to db and render it on pageload

Comment: If you want this permanently then you have to save the number of row in database then you can display  it on page load

Comment: You can't pass data from a session to another unless you store it somewhere.

If you want to save the data and have it available in your system you need to store it in a database, therefore the data needs to be sent to your system. On refresh the data is loaded from your server/database.

Otherwise you can try to store the data using the Web Storage (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), which allows the users to store the data locally on their computer even if they haven't sent it to your system. On refresh the data is loaded from their local computer.

Comment: Use cookie, below answer was tested in all browsers. NO need to store value in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Use cookie, **run below code in your LOCAL** and refresh the page. See magic.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var getControl=getCookie("countControls1");
 var max_fields_limit = 10; // Set limit for maximum input fields
  var x = 0; // Initialize counter for text box
 for(var i=1; i<=getControl; i++)
 {
  console.log(i);
  addControls();
 }
  
  $('.add_more_button').click(function (e) { // Click event to add more fields
    addControls();
  });  
 function addControls()
 {
  console.log(x);
  if (x < max_fields_limit) 
  { 
   x++; // Increment counter
   setCookie("countControls1",x,100);
   $('.input_fields_container').append('<div><input type="text" id="id'+x+'" name="product_name[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field" style="margin-left:10px;">Remove</a></div>'); // Add input field
  }
 }
    $('.input_fields_container').on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { // User click on remove text links
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
  setCookie("countControls1",x,100);
   });
   
 function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
  $("#div1").html("Add cookie = ",getCookie(cname));
 }
 function getCookie(cname) 
 {
  console.clear();
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  //console.log(cname);
  //console.log(decodedCookie);
  console.log(ca);
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) 
  {
   var c = ca[i];
   while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') 
   {
    c = c.substring(1);
   }
   if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) 
   {
    console.log(c.substring(name.length, c.length));
    return (c.substring(name.length, c.length));
   }
  }
  return "";
 }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="add_more_button" value="Add" />
<div class="input_fields_container"></div>
```